# NetBeans Free Design

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

Being using Layout managers to design my GUI forms. If I decide to use the Netbeans free design layout manager, would I have any disadvantage implementing the forms on different platforms and screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have screen resolution issues on Free layout since they are not responsive because the positions that You are setting are Absolute. So You can't just go ahead and set something floating. You will drag it to a place, and Netbeans will set it to position x,y.